# (Silently) failing to create custom attribute for category

Tags: magento-1.9, module, category-attribute

I am trying to add some custom attributes to my categories in Magento.

So Ive created my first ever module which would add a single custom attribute, by following the tutorial here: http://gauss-development.com/blog/tutorials/adding-custom-category-attributes-magento/

Everything seems to be working fine, the modules appears to be installed (I can see it in System > Advanced > Disable Modules Output).

But my custom attributes are not appearing. At all.

Ive been through the tutorial for the last 4 days. Over and over again. Following it as closely as possible, copy and pasting wherever possible. Other tutorials I have seem appear to be similar to this, I tried following them as well. All of these tutorials end up with the same results, no errors, nothing appears to be wrong, the modules appear to be loaded, but no sign of my new custom attributes appearing.

I feel I am missing something not mentioned in these tutorials, but I have no idea what.

Can anybody think of anything I could be doing wrong?

If you need to look at any code, please look at the tutorial mentioned above. Is there a piece of information, or instruction that tutorial is missing? Remember I have no other experience with creating modules, so I am following these to the letter. If they are assuming I would have a basic piece of information, this is probably where I am slipping up, but currently I have no way of knowing what I am missing.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: have check compiler is enable or not?

Comment: clear the cache if not done yet

Comment: cache has been cleared, flushed and re-cleared / all indexes have re-index and re-indexed once more / compiler has been enabled, disable and enabled again... none of these things have made any difference - is there anything else I should check?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code to add attribute for categories.
You can create your custom module for this.
**app/code/local/Custom/CustomCategoryAttribute/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_CustomCategoryAttribute>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Custom_CustomCategoryAttribute>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>Custom_CustomCategoryAttribute</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute>
            <add_category_attribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_write>
            <add_category_attribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Custom/CustomCategoryAttribute/sql/add_category_attribute/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php**

```
<?php

$this->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'category_long_description', array(
    'group' => 'General',
    'input' => 'textarea',
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Category Long Description',
    'backend' => '',
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Comment: thanks for the response! Unfortunately this results in the same problem, I can see the module in Disable Modules Output, there are zero errors - but I cant find this custom attribute _anywhere_... Any idea's as to what I might be doing wrong? (This is after flushing caches, re-indexing everything, and logging off and back on again btw)

Comment: I can see the new attribute under catalog -> Managge categories -> [Any category] -> General tab

Comment: I cannot... at all... Any idea why this could be?

Comment: Can you please check if the sql gets executed, by checking the entry in core_resource table

Comment: I can see `CustomCatAttrb_setup` in there, version and data version are bother `0.0.1`

Comment: Please check this attribute's entry in category tables as well. I don't remember the exact table name.

Comment: Hmmm... well I can't see it, but I'm not entire sure where to look

Answer (score 0):

please check if the attribute appears in your database, you can search in the database table **eav_attribute** in field **attribute_code** for the name of your attribute (as an example from my files below, it would be **cat_short_description**. If it not appears there in the Database then there is some error in your modul-setup.

The Code i used (file etc/config.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Andreabiedermann_Categoryattributes>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Andreabiedermann_Categoryattributes>
</modules>

<global>
    <resources>
        <Categoryattributes_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Andreabiedermann_Categoryattributes</module>
                <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>default_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </Categoryattributes_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
</config>
```

and mysql4-install-0.0.1.php under sql/Categoryattributes_setup/

```
$this->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'cat_short_description', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Short Description',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'default'       => '',
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'user_defined'  =>  true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Please Check that **group** is set to "General Information", if it is not it will not appear in your General Tab in the Category view.

Another error your could check is if the files have the right names. It should have the right version number in it.

Also, if there were an error in the past and you want to correct it you need to reinitialize the setup process for your module. To do so, please delete module-entry in the **core_resource** table, logout from backend and log back in. You need to do this every time you want the setup script to run again.